# CSS for login form is not loading

Tags: php, html, css, forms, authentication

Revised question. Trying to make the situation as clear as possible.
I downloaded a login system for my existing website. So as not to mess with my index.php, I set it up in its own folder (login-system). Got it all to work. I copy pasted relevant code to my index.php in the root and changed all paths to "login-system/whatever.php". Even though I changed the paths, it still won't work correctly. Specifically the css. The login form has its own css file (login-system/css/css.html) included like this:

.
In css.html are 3 links (google fonts, normalize and css/style.css)
I cannot get the login form's css AND the existing css (main.css) to work together. I either get my page looking fine and login form has no css or I get the login form with its css messing up my page. What do I need to do?
Here is the relevant code:

    
    
    
    
    
    The Living Oracles.org

```
</head>
<?php 
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') 
{
    if (isset($_POST['login'])) { //user logging in

        require '/login-system/login.php';

    }

    elseif (isset($_POST['register'])) { //user registering

        require '/login-system/register.php';

    }
}
?>
<body>

    <div class ="login">

   <div class="form">

            <ul class="tab-group">
            <li class="tab"><a href="#signup">Sign Up</a>
            </li>
            <li class="tab active"><a href="#login">Log In</a>
            </li>
        </ul>

        <div class="tab-content">

            <div id="login">
                <h1>Welcome Back!</h1>

                <form action="index.php" method="post" autocomplete="off">

                    <div class="field-wrap">
                        <label>
              Email Address<span class="req">*</span>
            </label>


                        <input type="email" required autocomplete="off" name="email"/>
                    </div>

                    <div class="field-wrap">
                        <label>
              Password<span class="req">*</span>
            </label>


                        <input type="password" required autocomplete="off" name="password"/>
                    </div>

                    <p class="forgot"><a href="forgot.php">Forgot Password?</a>
                    </p>

                    <button class="button button-block" name="login"/>Log In</button>

                </form>
<script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>

    <script src="login-system/js/index.js"></script>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Remove `<?php include '/login-system/css/css.html'; ?>` and change `<link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">` to `<link href="login-system/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">`

Comment: Sorry, that didn't work.

Comment: are you getting any error?

Comment: What’s in `/login-system/css/css.html`? If it really contains HTML, then why is in the `head` section?

Comment: No error. It's just not recognizing the css for the form. The css.html contains this:   <!DOCTYPE html>
  <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web:400,300,600" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="login-css/style.css">

Comment: @manngo That is how it was set up in the code I downloaded.

Comment: @manngo I still need an answer to this question. Do you have one? Do you know where I can get one? Thanks.

Comment: @Newsong80 I need an answer too: what’s in `/login-system/css/css.html`? Is it really HTML or other content?

Comment: @Manngo It is a link to google fonts, a link to "normalize" and a link to css/css.html

Comment: @Newsong80 Could you please display the contents? You mention a link to `css/css.html`. That sounds circular. What happens if you just remove that line?

Comment: @Manngo Nothing happened. It remained the same. This was all working when the code was in the same folder as the rest of the login files.

Comment: @Manngo my css file and the css file for the form are in two different places so that is why I don't understand why they don't both work at the same time.

Comment: @Manngo Let me ask the question differently. I have a nav bar with styled links. I also have a login form with styled links. In general, how do I keep the styles separated so that, for example, my login form link styles don't overwrite my nav bar link styles?

Comment: @Manngo I figured it out.